# GPUボードが複数ある Ubuntu 20.04でディスプレイ出力に使うGPUを指定したい

Tags: ubuntu, gpu

GeForce GTX 1080Tiを2枚とGeForce GT 1030をセットしたPCに
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS をインストールいたしました。

1030をディスプレイ出力に、1080Tiの方を機械学習に使用したいと思うのですが
1030からディスプレイ出力する方法がわからず困っております。

`$ lspci | grep VAG` の結果は以下の通りです。

```
　17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
　65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
　b3:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
```

解決方法あるいはヒントなどご教示いただければありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

お騒がせしました。以下のとおり自己解決しました。

1. `$ lspci | grep VGA`

   ```
   　17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
   　65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
   　b3:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
   ```
2. `$ sudo nvidia-xconfig` --> /etc/X11/xorg.conf 生成
3. 1.で確認した"b3:00.0"を10進数に変換する --> 179:0:0
4. /etc/X11/xorg.conf の「Section "Device"」のVenderNameの項目の下に下記を追加

   ```
   BusID          "PCI:179:0:0"
   ```
5. `sudo reboot`

以下のリンクが参考になると思います。

[16.7. GPU デバイスの割り当て Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 | Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-device-gpu)

ありがとうございました。